# A question regarding extendible cardinals and a result of M. Magidor

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, mathematical-philosophy

The following definitions and Theorems come from M. Magidor's paper "On the Role of Supercompact and Extendible Cardinals in Logic" (Israel J. Math., Vol. 10, 1971):

"Definition:  Logic is called $\kappa$ compact iff for every set of formulae A in this logic, if every subset of A of cardinality $\lt$$\kappa$ has a model, then A has a model.

The $L^{n}_{\kappa}$ logic is like the n-th order logic, except that we allow conjunction and disjunctions of less than $\kappa$ formulae.  The usual second order logic is of course $L^{2}_{\omega}$.

Theorem 4.  $\kappa$ is extendible iff $L^{2}_{\kappa}$ is $\kappa$ compact.  $\kappa$ is the first extendible iff it is the first $\alpha$ such that second order logic is $\alpha$ compact." He also proves this theorem as well:  "if $\kappa$ is extendible it is supercompact".  However, nowhere in his paper does he say whether he is using full semantics or Henkin models when he refers to $\kappa$ compactness.  I therefore will go out on a limb here (so to speak) and presume (rightly or wrongly) that he is using full semantics rather than Henkin models (after all, he does speak of "the usual second order logic" and that, I suppose, might be a subtle indication that he means to use full semantics).

Under this assumption, it is well known that $L^{2}_{\omega}$ is not compact.  Under this assumption, it seems one can prove the noncompactness of $L^{2}_{\omega}$ using Theorem 4 and "if $\kappa$ is extendible then it is supercompact".  I argue in the following manner:  by Theorem 4, if $L^{2}_{\omega}$ is $\omega$ compact (i.e. compact) then $\omega$ is extendible.  If $\omega$ is extendible it is supercompact.  However, in his answer to arsmath's mathoverflow question, "$\aleph_0$ (arsmath writes it "Aleph 0") as a large cardinal", Amit Kumar Gupta shows that $\omega$ is not supercompact, hence by this, the chain of contrapositives of the implications I use and modus ponens, $L^{2}_{\omega}$ is not $\omega$ compact (i.e. not compact).

This, however, raises the following question:  even if $L^{2}_{\omega}$ is not compact, by Theorem 4, if there exists some extendible $\kappa$ ($\gt$$\omega$) then $L^{2}_{\kappa}$ is $\kappa$ compact (i.e. second order logic satisfies some compactness theorem).  Those who do not believe in the existence of large cardinals should ask themselves whether second order logic should be $\kappa$ compact under full semantics.  Another question that arises is this:  since $L^{2}_{\omega}$ is compact under Henkin models, does Theorem 4 hold over Henkin models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, the answer is "no." Since, with Henkin semantics, second-order logic is just re-syntacted first-order logic, of course theorem 4 fails for Henkin semantics: $L_\kappa^2$ with Henkin semantics is compact iff $L_{\kappa,\omega}$ is compact - that is, iff $\kappa$ has the *tree property* (which is implied by, but not equivalent to, $\kappa$ being weakly compact - weakly compact = tree property *plus inaccessible*).

Meanwhile, I'm not sure what your first question is asking. It is quite reasonable to have a sequence of stronger logics $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$ ($\alpha\in ON$) such that compactness fails early ($\mathcal{L}_\omega$ is not $\omega$-compact) but holds occasionally later on ($\mathcal{L}_\kappa$ is $\kappa$-compact for some $\kappa$). For instance, take $\mathcal{L}_\alpha=L_{\aleph_\alpha,\omega}$. Then $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$ is compact iff $\aleph_\alpha$ has the tree property - in particular, it is enough for $\alpha$ to be weakly compact. So I don't see what challenge this raises for "those who do not [or do?] believe in the existence of large cardinals."

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer.  Since Theorem 4  does not hold under Henkin semantics, it is clear that Magidor was assuming $L^2_{\kappa}$ with full semantics.

Comment: (cont.)  I will have to think about the question posed in the second part of your answer.  Is there some way '$L^2_{\kappa}$ is $\kappa$-compact' could be shown to be independent of $L^2_{\kappa}$ ( a type of forcing argument, for instance)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I'm not sure what you mean by "Is there some way '$L_\kappa^2$ is $\kappa$-compact could be shown to be independent of $L_\kappa^2$' - can you clarify?

Comment: Some further questions.  Under full semantics, it is known that $L^2_{\omega}$ is incomplete, that is, the set of truths and the set of falsities of $L^2_{\omega}$ each are not r.e. (what is the position of each of these sets in the Kleene hierarchy)?  If $L^2_{\omega}$ is incomplete, then is $L^2_{\kappa}$ also incomplete under full semantics as well?  Let me assume now, for the sake of argument, that the sentence "$L^2_{\kappa}$  is $\kappa$-compact" is independent of $L^2_{\kappa}$.  Then $\lnot$$L^2_{\kappa}$ is not provable in $L^2_{\kappa}$ either, so one can have

Comment: (cont.) models of full semantics in which either "$L^2_{\kappa}$ is $\kappa$-compact" or "$\lnot$$L^2_{\kappa}$ is $\kappa$-compact" holds.  Is there some reason that  " '$L^2_{\kappa}$ is ${\kappa}$-compact' is independent of $L^2_{\kappa}$"  is not tenable?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I don't understand what you're asking. First of all, I wouldn't say $L_\omega^2$ is "incomplete" - to me, (in)completeness is a property of **proof systems**, not logics, and the point is that there is no complete proof system (appropriately defined) for $L_\omega^2$. I'm not sure what "$L_\kappa^2$ is incomplete" should mean, so I don't know if it's true or false. Finally, I still don't know what "'$L_\kappa^2$ is $\kappa$-compact' is independent of $L_\kappa^2$" means! A sentence isn't independent of a *logic*, but of a *theory* - what's the theory here? (cont'd)

Comment: As to your paranthetical question: the set of tautologies of $L_\omega^2$ is **ludicrously* complicated, well beyond the arithmetic hierarchy. It's a good exercise to show that e.g. the true $(\omega17+34)$th-order theory of the natural numbers is reducible to the set of $L_\omega^2$-tautologies (the key here is that $\omega17+34$ is second-order definable, appropriately); and this can be pushed further up. But it gets worse! As you know, second-order validity is not forcing invariant - there is a second order sentence which is a tautology iff CH holds - but it doesn't stop there: (cont'd)

Comment: its *Turing degree* isn't even absolute! Fix a model $V$ of ZFC, and a real $r$ in $V$. Then there is a forcing extension $V[G]$ such that the set of $L_\omega^2$-validities - let's call it "$T_\omega^2$" - in $V[G]$ computes $r$! Just make $V[G]$ such that $\{k: 2^{\aleph_{2k}}=2^{\aleph_{2k+1}}\}=r$. So in an appropriate sense, the set of $L_\omega^2$ tautologies is "arbitrarily complicated." For instance, combining this with the absoluteness of $L$ and the Levy collapse, "$\forall x\in L\cap\mathbb{R}(T_\omega^2\ge_T x)$" is consistent with ZFC.

Comment: A neat exercise: the set of validities of $L_\omega^3$ is Turing equivalent (in fact, recursively isomorphic) to $T_\omega^2$.

Comment: What is your definition of a 'proof system' and how do you distinguish it from a 'logic'  and a 'theory'?   A 'theory', of course will have 'non-logical axioms' but can't a 'logic' under certain circumstances also be a 'proof system'?  To my mind, at least, a 'logic' need not be a closed system--there can exist true but unprovable logical truths and there can even exist undecidable logical truths (denote $LT$ as one) so that one can have separate logics with $LT$ or $\lnot$$LT$ as 'axioms'.  Why cannot this be the case?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin By "logic," I mean just the set of formulas and the satisfaction relation. A "theory" in a given logic is just a set of formulas in that logic. There isn't, so far as I know, a universal definition of "proof system", **which is part of the reason I'm asking you what you mean**, but at the very least it's a relation on $\{$sets of formulas$\}\times\{$formulas$\}$, telling us when some formula is "provable from" a set of formulas, which is compatible with the obvious notion of semantic entailment (that is, soundness holds appropriately). (cont'd)

Comment: We can then add additional requirements onto the definition: maybe the proof system, as a relation, should be recursively enumerable. Or something else. The point is, things like natural deduction, or semantic tableaux, or sequent calculus, are readily verified to have all of these properties in connection with first-order logic; completeness theorems then states that the proof systems are complete for the logic. The sentence "first-order logic is complete" is shorthand. Note that my usage of these terms is basically what e.g. "Model-theoretic logics" uses, and most of abstract model theory.

Comment: If you don't like how I'm using these terms, that's fine, but I promise you I'm not being deliberately thick: **I really don't understand what you are asking here**.

Comment: I just wanted some clarification, that's all.  Regarding the notion of "proof system", I just wanted to check if a proof system was somehow different from a set of rules of inference.  My point was that I have no problem with the notion of incomplete proof systems, that is, proof systems that do not (as in the case of second-order logic) derive all of the 'true sentences' of the 'logic' and in the case of second-order logic, have no problems with a sentence of second-order logic  or its negation not being derivable by 'the' proof system for second-order logic (like $CH$ for

Comment: (cont.) $ZFC$).  I hope I have not muddied the waters further....